# How to get the number of registered users group by date and get the result without time?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

```
$rows = Registrant::select(DB::raw('count(*) as number, created_at'))
                      ->whereBetween( DB::raw('date(created_at)'), [$fromDate, $tillDate] )
                      ->groupBy(DB::raw('date(created_at)'))
                      ->get();
```

The above query gives me the following result:

```
[{"number":4,"created_at":"2017-11-08 17:57:37"}]
```

Which is quite correct except I only want date to present without time (17:57:37)? How do I remove the time to get this:

```
[{"number":4,"created_at":"2017-11-08"}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply replace

```
DB::raw('count(*) as number, created_at')
```

with

```
DB::raw('count(*) as number, DATE(created_at)')
```